# git successfully push to private github repositories even token expired

Tags: git, github

last month I add token to my github account because i cant push a commit to my private repo

and I add a expiry date to it

and now after reading some email I read github email about my expired token

and I go to my account and make sure it is expired and it is

and I wonder why I can still push commit to my private repo

so I destroy all token but still it push

is this a problem of github?
or its my fault?

please explain what's happening
my expected result is when the token expired git should ask me a new token

by the way I don't know what I have done this last few weeks but when i pushing commit git not asking for username and my password

it just pushing automatically

Comment: Are you using an SSH connection? It's possible that you've set up an SSH key, those are independent of private tokens (which are used for HTTPS connections).

Comment: i am in remote machine (VPS) and i am using ssh to connect to that machine

but i cloning my private repo using https

Answer (score 1):

The time you push your first commit (through command line or GitHub API), it saves your credentials and uses them (as global "variables"), whenever you push again.

The token you created is just another way of pushing, instead of your password. When the token is expired, you can still commit and push, but with your original credentials (meaning email, username, password).

Comment: but password is failing if i use my password so i use token then it works. but now the token expire but still i can push

Comment: the token was used as your password. so now it's saved to your environment and it's not necessary to use the password.

Comment: so github allows it even the token expired?

Comment: it doesn't use the token anymore. GitHub recognizes your machine that is valid for your account, so it allows the commit to get pushed.

Comment: so it means if i use that token to new device it wont work?

Comment: if you're sure that the token has expired, I guess so.

Comment: i destroy it. let me try it later thanks for helping

Comment: @GiannisZapantis: do you have any source for that "Github recognizes your machine" statement?

Comment: No. But I have tried it on 3 different computers, with different os, and once I log in (from the command line or vs code, for example), it never asks me for credentials again. And the first time it didn't ask me to "save them forever" or something like that.

Comment: thanks @GiannisZapantis i tried it on new machine and it ask the token then the token fails

Comment: It should give you the choice to log in with your official credentials.